# Git says file was deleted but will not allow pulling

Tags: git

I am running windows, I attempted to pull the master branch of a project
and I get this, I am scared that master is broken. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
PS C:\Users\Name\source\work\PROJ\PROJ> git status
HEAD detached at 274a1c9
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    "PROJ.API/c:\\temp\\internal-nlog.txt"

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
PS C:\Users\Name\source\work\PROJ\PROJ> git rm PROJ.API/C:\\temp\\internal-nlog.txt
```

when I attempt to stage it, I get this:

[image]

Comment: The feedback from `git status` seems to be saying that you currently in the detached HEAD state, which means that the branch isn't currently on any actual commit.  How did you get to this state?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, someone on Unix has added a file that is not a valid file name on Windows. As long as that file exists in the repository, `git status` on your machine will show this "deleted" file. From the name, it looks like it was a mistake, though, so you could remove it:

```
git update-index --force-remove "PROJ.API/c:\\temp\\internal-nlog.txt"
```

I'm not entirely sure how PowerShell will handle the backslashes, though. You could also try to create a text file `filename.txt` whose only line is that file name, and do:

```
Get-Content filename.txt | git update-index --force-remove --stdin
```

Comment: I wonder what the tree structure looks like. What does `git ls-tree HEAD` show you? Is there one line where the file name is `PROJ.API`, or one with the entire file name? If the former, what does `git ls-tree HEAD PROJ.API` show?

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin you are in a detached state.

Do you you want to keep the `internal-nlog.txt file`?

Either way, this is probably the easiest way forward:

**1. Stash the current changes:**

`git stash`

You have stashed away the changes you made (i.e. you deleted the internal-nlog file). You can retrieve it later if you want.

**2. Go to the master branch**

`git checkout master`

And everything should work out fine.